# JavaFx Crash in Windows 7 machines

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

We are working on JavaFx for alerting application on desktops, but its showing very random crash issue in different machine, there is no pattern for CPU or memory consumption.

on machines with good RAM more than 6GB Windows Server 2008, it is crashing on 85 alerts and on machines with 2GB RAM Windows XP it goes upto 300+ alerts.

I tried with jconsole, it shown CPU peak to 10-15% before crash. and mostly it scrashes in Windows 7 machines.

then i tried running my application with -Xcheck:jni parameter with JVM and it shows following error :

with java 7_40
FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad global or local ref passed to JNI

with java 8 it run but with following warning message
Warning: Calling other JNI functions in the scope of Get/ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical or Get/ReleaseStringCritical

I know this question is not much clear, but this is all data i have, can anyone guide me from where and how i should start debugging this issue?

Comment: post this issue on official JavaFX bug tracker: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/ providing crash dump and detailed machine config (e.g. GPU and drivers versions)

Comment: there is a known issue concerning JavaFX dialog boxes on Windows 2008 server systems. It shall be fixed in Java 8 though. Try checking the JavaFX-Bugtracker Jira https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/ (registration is free)

Comment: Is there any way for debugging? how can i get these dump file? any link for tutorials? I cant wait for java8, i need some work around till that time.

Comment: Updating to latest Java-8 made the application stable and much more efficient than before. Still no clue what was happened.